# Sections of 'Glass' object show black when in front of PNG

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

You can see by the attached image that my sections of 'Glass' shelf object show black when in front of PNG, and fine when not in frot of the graphic. Any ideas? Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your bottle material is black to everything except the camera:

[image]

Long story short, when you see the material through the glass you see it as the glass "sees" it; i.e. 0 strength emission (black).

See [the manual](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html) for more information about ray types.

If what you want to do is prevent the material from illuminating the diffuse floor, then instead you could make the material black only to diffuse rays:

[image]

[image]

---

*Unrelated, but you also seem to have a couple extra bottle objects occupying the same space. Not sure if that was intentional or not.*

Comment: Can you please upload the blend file so I can deconstruct and understand better? Unrelated: I forgot to delete the unused extra bottle objects ---sorry if it made things more confusing)

Comment: Should your initial comment of "This is because your bottle material is back to everything except the camera" --- actually read BLACK not BACK?

Comment: @Marc Ah, yes my bad. Good catch :)